# How to use method invoker in IF statement in C# to check for Gridvalues

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker

I am trying to check if Invoke is required , and if success I'm trying to access GridView to check for any values and doing something, But when I trying to access the Gridview it is throwing an exception, of Crossthreading, Please help me.
Here is the code :

```
       if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {     
               if ((_grdAccBills.Tag == null) ||
                 (_grdAccBills.Tag.ToString() !=
 (TxtAccNumber.Text.Trim() + "|" + ((Property != null) ? Property.HMY.ToString() : "0"))))
                 {
                     //do sometihng
                }
           }));
      }
```

This is the exception :

{"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '_grdAccBills' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."}

Comment: Complete call stack from exception should tell you where problem comes from. At this point your post does not have enough information to suggest what's wrong (or even if anything is wrong) with code you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted should work correctly, from the code, I need to make guesses of what can be wrong.

when you get Crossthreading exception, the code accessing the control is not on the same thread that created the control. `this.Invoke` brings the code into the main UI thread of `this` which is most probably a `Form`. So the main UI thread of `this` `Form` should be different from `_grdAccBills`. That is:

1. Is `this` `Form` different from the `Form` that owns `_grdAccBills`?
2. Is `_grdAccBills` created on a different thread? Then it should no be able to be shown on `this` `Form`

Any more info about the structure of your UI might help to pinpoint the problem.

Finally, something that is not causing the exception, but is wrong in the code: the code should run correctly when called from a different thread, but it will dot nothing in run from the main UI thread. The right way to do it is:

```
var method = new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    //your code
});
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    Invoke(method);
}
else
{
    method();
}
```